# How to pass php value to script variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php variable value and we have to pass it to a script variable automatically on a button click. Please suggest me.

```
<?php
$query2 = mysql_query("select * from video_detail where video_id='$id' and status=1");
while( $qry2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
    $part1 = $qry2["part"];
    $from1 = $qry2["from"];
    $to1 = $qry2["to"];
?>
    <button><? echo $part1;?></button><? }?><br>

    <video style="border:1px solid" id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
        <source src="uploads/videos/<?php echo $vid;?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <script>
      var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
      var videoStartTime = 0;
      var durationTime = 0;

      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        videoStartTime = 2;
        durationTime = 4;
        this.currentTime = videoStartTime;
      }, false);

      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        if(this.currentTime > videoStartTime + durationTime){
          this.pause();
        }
      });
    </script>
```

When I click button `$from1` value passed to `videoStartTime` = ??; and `$to1` value passed to `durationTime` = ??;

Comment: Where is the variable?

Comment: You have this script tag in your HTML file, right? Then you could just do `<?php print(variable) ?>` in there.

Comment: i have to store $from1 $to1 value in place of  2,4

Comment: all i want is to start a video on a click button..and fetch start stop  values of video from that clicked id from database automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
<script> 

    var form1 = <?= $form1 ?>;
    var to1 = <?= $to1 ?>;

 </script>
```

Add an event to your button like:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

And overwrite the values inside this function when onclick event happens:

```
function myFunction(){
   videoStartTime = form1;
   durationTime = to1;
}
```